# Web roo and user session

Tags: spring-roo

I am new to spring roo and I have had some difficulties finding out the ressources needed to go forward with my projet.

I would like to use a finder, see this answer:
[In Spring Roo : what is a dynamic finder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5224401/in-spring-roo-what-is-a-dynamic-finder)

Now I would like to use the logged-in username as parameter of a finder.
How could I do  ?

Answer (score 0):

You can list all available finders and add the finder you need to your application using [the following documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/reference/html/command-index.html#command-index-finder-commands). You can read more in [corresponding question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5224401/680503).

Then you can modify corresponding method in corresponding Spring MVC controller adding `Principal` parameter the following way:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)   
public ModelAndView showResults(final HttpServletRequest request, Principal principal) {
    final String currentUser = principal.getName();
    ...
}
```

Remember you should't modify it right in ITD but you should copy it to the corresponding *.java controller first. In this method you should modify list which used inside with usage of your finder.

And finally you can exclude your dynamic finders from scaffolding by using `exposeFinders=false` of [`RooWebScaffold`](http://static.springsource.org/spring-roo/org.springframework.roo.annotations/apidocs/org/springframework/roo/addon/web/mvc/controller/RooWebScaffold.html) annotation.

Comment: Exactly and how can I fetch the authentificated username so I can add it as the parameter of my finder ?

Comment: I've added more details which can be useful.

Comment: Thank you.
Why do you use principal.getName() and not SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName() ?

Comment: Adding this parameter Spring 3 can inject `Principal` automatically.